# Suspend Twilio SMS Message

Tags: twilio, sms, message

My app currently has a twilio api call to send SMS to clients on a certain timing.  I am looking to temporarily cancel or suspend the message but am unsure how to do it.  Is this possible without deleting the number or adjusting the code?

Answer (score 0):

You can change your API keys, but this would impact **all** applications using those API keys. You would then need to update the keys in your application(s) once you are ready to begin sending again.

[Auth Tokens and How to Change Them (rotate credentials)](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223136027-Auth-Tokens-and-How-to-Change-Them)

Another possibility, again which impacts **all** applications using **SMS**, is to restrict the SMS geographic permissions to all the countries you are sending to, until you are ready to start sending again, then re-enable them.

Other than that, given your restrictions of not touching the application or the phone number used by the application, the 2nd option may be best, again clearly understanding the impact of these changes.

[How International SMS Permissions work](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223181108-How-International-SMS-Permissions-work)